# Cannot drop database — conflicting evidence on number of users accessing the database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

On PostgreSQL 9.6.6, running on Amazon RDS

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'my_db'
```

yields nothing.

However, trying to drop the database

```
DROP DATABASE my_db;
```

fails with:

> ERROR:  database "my_db" is being accessed by other users DETAIL: 
>   There are 3 other sessions using the database.

I've tried to lock down the number of conns to the db with these <s>two</s> three:

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE my_db FROM public;
ALTER DATABASE my_db CONNECTION LIMIT 0;
ALTER DATABASE my_db WITH ALLOW_CONNECTIONS false;
```

I do have read replication set up (however — this shouldn't block as this is reading off the WAL?) and occasional snapshotting (not during the `DROP` stmt is being run though).

What are these three lingering conns and how do I get rid of them?